# Looping and evaulating with SpEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

First of all, please consider I am beginner as a developer and as a Spring user too.
I am searching for a solution to this problem:

There is a given list filled with JsonNode objects, called attributes. I have to find which one is evaulating true against a given boolean expression. I would like to register a collection in a context, iterating over it and finding if any attributes evaulate true with SpEl, so I don't have to make this quite expensive context creation every time.

Do you have any idea how to do it faster? (The code is dummy. Problem is real.)

```
//given
List<JsonNode> attributes;

attributes
    .stream()
    .anyMatch(attribute -> {
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("attribute.name == 'John Doe'");
        EvaluationContext ctx = new StandardEvaluationContext(attribute);
        return exp.getValue(ctx, Boolean.class);
    });
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse and build a context for each element; you can pass the root object into the `getValue()`.

Parse the expression once and use `getValue(context, attribute, Boolean.class)` instead.

Unless you need to customize the context, you don't even need one.

```
getValue(attribute, Boolean.class)
```